# Why is LinkedListNode Next property readonly?

Tags: c#

I've been working on LeetCode problems using C# and have noticed an issue when trying to set a linkedlistnode's next value to a new node, which is that **'property or indexer ......Next cannot be assigned to -- it is read only'**. I can read from node's next, but **cannot** assign a node to a node's next. Why is this the case with .NET?

```
var l1Value = l1 == null ? 0 : l1.Value;
var l2Value = l2 == null ? 0 : l2.Value;
var newNode = new LinkedListNode<int>((l1Value + l2Value + overflow) % 10);
start.Next = newNode; <------ red squiggly
start = start.Next; <------ no red squiggly
```

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, not a framework and not a language. It doesn't have a `LinkedListNode`, but .NET has one. Please use correct terms

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Added the terms IDE and .NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `AddBefore`/`AddAfter`/`AddFirst`/`AddLast` methods on `LinkedList` to add elements to your list.

I don't know 100% but I assume the API surface does not allow you to modify `Next` element of a `LinkedListNode` because that would allow you to end up with weird things like cycles, incomplete lists, etc. Mainly things that make of an inconsistent state. The documentation says `LinkedList` does not support that:

> **The `LinkedList<T>` class does not support chaining, splitting, cycles, or other features that can leave the list in an inconsistent state.** The list remains consistent on a single thread. The only multithreaded scenario supported by `LinkedList<T>` is multithreaded read operations.

Instead of exposing the low level `Next`/`Previous` properties with setters the authors decided it's better to provide methods to accomplish the common insertion/deletion operations and make sure all the right things happen. E.g. they make sure both `Next` and `Previous` get updated on every insert/delete. If they allowed you to modify `Next` or `Previous` directly it wouldn't be possible to make sure both are always updated when necessary. You can still accomplish what you need but they limited the possibility of bugs when people implement these operations themselves.

Comment: Not exactly. You should do `var list = new LinkedList<int>` and later when you want to add a node you can just do `list.AddFirst(5)`. Instead of holding on to the node that's the head of the list you should hold and use the `list` itself.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the class if you can't do mid-list insertions in constant time.  That's the whole reason I'd ever think to use a linked list.  Otherwise, a queue or stack would do the job.

Comment: @Casey You can. `AddBefore`/`AddAfter` are both O(1).

Answer (score 2):

`Next` property has only getter that returns the next item from `LinkedListNode`.

I think you are looking for `start.List.AddLast(newNode)`.

Hope helps,

Comment: Is this the convention for C#? I always thought start.Next = newNode would be the best way to go about setting the next node in the LinkedList

Comment: That is not the way to set next node in C#. You should use AddLast(), AddBefore, AddAfter etc to set nodes. @springathing